# How to print all values of same/duplicate keys from JSON/dictionary?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, key

From this below dictionary, how can I print only 'test1' values, suppose there will be multiple 'test1' keys, how can I print all of its values?

```
data = {"test1" : "PASS", "test2" : "FAILED", "test3" : "PASS", "test1" : "FAILED"}
```

such that it gives output PASS for test1 at index 0 as well as FAIL for test1 at index 3, because dictionary only counts the last most value, FAILED in this case. 
required output:

```
PASS
FAILED
```

any work around?

Comment: You can't have a dictionary like this. Alternative - you can try `defaultdict(list)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary can only contain unique keys. So, in your case `data` cannot be a dictionary. You could make `data` a list or defaultdict instead.

Say, for `data = [("test1","PASS"), ("test2","FAILED"),("test3","PASS"), ("test1", "FAILED")]`

Then doing this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

test_result = defaultdict(list) 
for test, result in data:
    test_result[test].append(result) 
print(test_result["test1"]) # gives ['PASS','FAILED']
```

Will give you the result you're looking for - All the results for a test

Comment: No I didn't get the desired output, can you please edit it with the complete code? because for me, same thing is happening like I mentioned above

Comment: I've edited it, so the results for test1 would return 'pass', 'fail'

Comment: Oh yes thanks! I guess the previous ans had "for test, result in test_result*:" which made me wonder if it's right or not, again thanks a lot